# Why would I need conversion?

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
template<class T>
struct Side
{
};

template<class T>
struct LeftSide : public Side<T>
{
};
template<class T>
struct RightSide : public Side<T>
{
};

Side<int>* f(int left, int right)
{
    return left < right ? new LeftSide<int> : new RightSide<int>;//<---Here I'm returning either left or right side
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error:
_Error  1   error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'RightSide *' to 'LeftSide *'_

I've thought (wrongly as I see) that I can assign pointer from derived to base without any problems. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is not with the conversion from either `LeftSide` or `RightSide` to `Side<T>`.  As you originally thought, this conversion would be fine.

Rather, the problem is with this expression:

```
left < right ? new LeftSide<int> : new RightSide<int>
```

Let's break this down a little.  The ternary operator (properly referred to in the Standard as the 'comparison operator') looks like this:

```
bool_val ? lhs_expression : rhs_expression
```

Keep in mind that this whole construct is itself an expression.  Meaning it returns a value, which has to have a type, obv.  The type of the *whole expression* is deduced from the types of `lhs_expression` and `rhs_expression`.  In this case, you have a `LeftSide` and a `RightSide`.  So, here's your problem.

`LeftSide` and `RightSide` are not directly related to each other other than having a common base class, and there's no conversion available between them. (You'd have to write one.)  So there's no single datatype that the `bool_val ? lhs_expression : rhs_expression` can have.  You might think, "well, silly compiler, why not just figure out the common base class and use that?"  This is, indeed, a bit of a pain.  Leaving the argument of it being Right or Wrong aside, it just doesn't work that way.

You have two options.

One, use a simpler construct:

```
if( left < right )
  return new LeftSide<int>;
else
  return new RightSide<int>;
```

Two, if you really really want to use the ternary operator (which is the case sometimes), you need to spoon-feed the compiler it's datatypes:

```
Side<int>* f(int left, int right)
{
    return left < right ? static_cast<Side<int>*>(new LeftSide<int>) : static_cast<Side<int>*>(new RightSide<int>);// now you're good
}
```

Comment: (1) You can't write user-defined conversions betweem pointer types.  (2) You only need to fix the type of one operand to make it work.  (3) Even `static_cast` is overkill since an implicit conversion exists, and `static_cast` could prevent the compiler from warning about legitimate type-safety issues.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the ? : operator requires that the 2 choices be the same type; not that they can be converted to the same type

FYI gcc fails the same

```
 error: conditional expression between distinct pointer types ‘LeftSide<int>*’ and ‘RightSide<int>*’ lacks a cast
```

casting both to Side(int)* works (but you probably knew that already)

Comment: Conversion is ok, but one operand has to be convertible to the type of the other.  If any type is allowed, the problem becomes intractable in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

You want both branches to return a `Side<int>*`, but the compiler doesn't know that, the type `Side<int>` doesn't appear anywhere in that expression.

Since I don't like to use a cast when an implicit conversion exists, I'd write this as:

```
 if (left < right) return new LeftSide<int>;
 return new RightSide<int>;
```

But if you want to use a ternary operator,

```
 Side<int>* i_want_this_type;
 return (left < right) ? new LeftSide<int> : (i_want_this_type = new RightSide<int>);
```

Now the right hand branch is type `Side<int>*`, the left hand is convertible to that type, everything is ok (and the compiler optimizes out the extra variable).

Comment: I wouldn't have d/v'ed but i'm guessing it's because you introduced a temporary -- even tho its a temporary the compiler may optimize in to vapor.

Answer (score 0):

The two should be the same type, or one should be convertible to the other.

```
return left < right ? (Side<int>*)new LeftSide<int> : (Side<int>*)new RightSide<int>;
```

Comment: A C-style cast is totally overkill here.

Comment: And brutally ugly and old-out-of-date-programmer-hasbeen-hack-ish